# Different P.values when using group_by followed by lm() compared to just lm() only

Tags: r, group-by, statistics, lm

Could I please get some help on the following. I have a data frame which has multiple groups which I would like to run a linear model on. As a test, I subset just one of the groups and ran the function lm() and got the following out put:

```
test <- filter(dat, locus == "ChrX_1")
test.result <- lm(methylation ~ Pheno, dat)

              term estimate  std.error statistic    p.value
1 (Intercept)   56.955      0.9729203 58.540254  9.080525e-250
2      Pheno1    9.015      1.1915791  7.565591  1.464884e-13
```

I then used group_by from dplyr package to perform the lm() function  on the different groups. But the output of the p.value of the locus "ChrX_1" is now different and weaker.

```
test.result4 <- group_by(dat, locus) %>%
  do(model.test2 = lm(methylation ~ Pheno, data = .))
tidy(test.result4, model.test2)  

    locus        term estimate std.error statistic      p.value
    <chr>       <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1   ChrX_1 (Intercept)    59.40  4.476666 13.268804 1.342225e-13
2   ChrX_1      Pheno1     9.05  5.482773  1.650624 1.099895e-01
3  ChrX_10 (Intercept)    59.00  4.069398 14.498459 1.522725e-14
4  ChrX_10      Pheno1    11.40  4.983974  2.287331 2.993721e-02
5  ChrX_11 (Intercept)    58.90  4.665565 12.624408 4.460131e-13
6  ChrX_11      Pheno1     9.10  5.714127  1.592544 1.224905e-01
7  ChrX_12 (Intercept)    52.80  3.717022 14.204921 2.526739e-14
8  ChrX_12      Pheno1    10.65  4.552403  2.339424 2.667444e-02
9  ChrX_13 (Intercept)    53.10  3.556734 14.929427 7.343091e-15
10 ChrX_13      Pheno1     7.10  4.356092  1.629901 1.143224e-01
# ... with 30 more rows
```

As such, I was wondering what is causing the weakening of the p.values?  I thought the p.value should be the same as when I had subsetted the locus and ran the lm() function on it.

Thanks

Comment: You are not using `test` dataset, instead using `dat`, when you are trying to `lm` for `locus == "ChrX_1"`. Is this the issue?

Comment: I suspect that you are using the entire dataset for the first `lm`. you needed to use `test` instead of `dat`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I completely missed that somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment, the issue is that you are not using the filtered data, instead you are using the entire dataset. Hence the mis-match.

Below is the code, with sample data, that shows no mismatch when using group_by and lm on it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(methylation=runif(1000, min=10, max=200), 
  Pheno=runif(1000, min=10, max=200), 
  locus=sample(paste0("ChrX_", 1:10), 1000, replace=TRUE)
  )
dat$locus <- as.character(dat$locus)

test <- filter(dat, locus == "ChrX_1")
test.result <- lm(methylation ~ Pheno, test)
summary(test.result)

test.result4 <- group_by(dat, locus) %>%
  do(model.test2 = lm(methylation ~ Pheno, data = .))
tidy(test.result4, model.test2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with iris and results for both approach are the same. there is something wrong with your group_by() line. Try it my way.

Look:

```
test <- filter(iris, Species=="setosa")
test.lm <- lm(Sepal.Length ~Sepal.Width, data=test)

  Species        term  estimate  std.error statistic      p.value
   <fctr>       <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1  setosa (Intercept) 2.6390012 0.31001431  8.512514 3.742438e-11
2  setosa Sepal.Width 0.6904897 0.08989888  7.680738 6.709843e-10
```

Then with group_by()

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(tidy(lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, data=.)))

 Species        term  estimate  std.error statistic      p.value
      <fctr>       <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1     setosa (Intercept) 2.6390012 0.31001431  8.512514 3.742438e-11
2     setosa Sepal.Width 0.6904897 0.08989888  7.680738 6.709843e-10
3 versicolor (Intercept) 3.5397347 0.56287357  6.288685 9.069049e-08
4 versicolor Sepal.Width 0.8650777 0.20193757  4.283887 8.771860e-05
5  virginica (Intercept) 3.9068365 0.75706053  5.160534 4.656345e-06
6  virginica Sepal.Width 0.9015345 0.25310551  3.561892 8.434625e-04
```